# How to efficiently load .kv files in a Kivy App

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm developping an application with multiple interfaces (about twenty screens) based on Kivy, and I want to know the best way (in terms of speed or performance) to load kv files ?

This is the two ways I have in mind

**Case 1**

Load each kv file in his corresponding interface definition file

```
[interface1.py]
...
Builder.load_file("path\to\interface1.kv")

class Interface1(Screen):
    # Class definition

...


[interface2.py]
...
Builder.load_file("path\to\interface2.kv")

class Interface2(Screen):
    # Class definition

...


[main.py]
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()

...
```

**Case 2**

Load kv files before run the app

```
[interface1.py]
...
class Interface1(Screen):
    # Class definition

...


[interface2.py]
...
class Interface2(Screen):
    # Class definition

...


[main.py]
...
Builder.load_file("path\to\interface1.kv")
Builder.load_file("path\to\interface2.kv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()

...
```

Comment: Both are equivalent because the load is given when you launch the application.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of always write new code for everynew kv file, I build it like the following method to load just by having the KV file in directory. Such as following:

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, isdir
from kivy.lang import Builder

# Gets current python dir then add the KV dir
kv_path = os.getcwd() + '/kv/'
kv_load_list = [f for f in listdir(kv_path) if isfile(join(kv_path, f))]

# Loads all KV file
for file in kv_load_list:
    if file.endswith('.kv'):
        Builder.load_file(kv_path + file)
```

Comment: What about using `glob` to get only kv files so that you do not need to check for it? Like `[f for f in glob.glob("*.kv")]`